# Finding limit points of the set $\{m-\sqrt2 n:m,n\in \mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: real-analysis

Find the limit points of the   set $\{m-\sqrt2 n:m,n\in \mathbb{N}\}$  in real numbers. Clearly every postive real number is a limit point what about negative reals?.

Comment: The proof you used for positive integers works perfectly for negative integers also!

Comment: Or equivalently, notice that if $x$ is a limit point not in the initial set $A$, then $x$ is the limit of some sequence $(a_k)_{k\geq 1}$ where $\lbrace a_k \rbrace$ is not finite. It follows that we may further assume that the $a_k$ are all distinct. It follows that we may further assume that there are sequences $(m_k)$ and $(n_k)$ tending to $+\infty$ such that $a_k=m_k-\sqrt{2}n_k$. Then, $x-n=\lim_{k}(a_k-n)$ is also a limite point for any $n\in{\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: Yes Thanking You......

Comment: for positive reals proof is given in problems in mathematical analysis-1 by W.J.Kaczor and W.T.Nowak...Thanking You...

Comment: Sir can you give simplest proof this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Continued Fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) approximations alternate between too big and too small. Furthermore, for Continued Fraction approximations of $\sqrt2$, we have
$$
\left|\,\frac pq-\sqrt2\,\right|\lt\frac1{q^2}
$$
for arbitrarily large $q$. This means that
$$
-\frac1q\lt\,p-q\sqrt2\lt\frac1q
$$
with arbitrary sign. To get within $\varepsilon$ of $-r$, we just need to find $p$ and $q$ so that $q\gt\frac1\varepsilon$ and $p-q\sqrt2\lt0$. Then
$$
-\varepsilon\lt p-q\sqrt2\lt0
$$
Let $k=\left\lfloor\frac{-r}{p-q\sqrt2}\right\rfloor$, then
$$
-r\lt kp-kq\sqrt2\lt-r+\varepsilon
$$
This shows that $m-n\sqrt2$ is dense in the negative reals.